# How to change style in <form>...</form>

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am not a web developer, but I have a task related to HTML/Javascript. Please treat me as a beginner. The problem is, for some reason, I need to put `<label ><input ><button >`in a `<form></form>` environment. However it looks more messy than before. I want to know how to make the style same as before.

*Original Code:*

```html
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row">
    <label id="email_label" for="email" style="padding-right:5px">Email:</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" style="flex:1" placeholder="enter email" />
    <button id="ack" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

It looks like this:
[image]

*New code:*

```html
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row">
  <form>
    <label id="email_label" for="email" style="padding-right:5px">Email:</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" style="flex:1" placeholder="enter email" />
    <button id="ack" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

which looks like:
[image]

When I click some other buttons, it becomes this:
[image]

I don't know why it changes.

Comment: what if you enclose the div in the form instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `display: flex` will now target only the `form`.
Change your code like this:

```
<form style="display:flex;flex-direction:row">
    <label id="email_label" for="email" style="padding-right:5px">Email:</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" style="flex:1" placeholder="enter email" />
    <button id="ack" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now it will target the label, input and button elements again.

As Jaromanda said:
You can also put the div inside the form like this:

```
<form>
  <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row">
    <label id="email_label" for="email" style="padding-right:5px">Email:</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" style="flex:1" placeholder="enter email" />
    <button id="ack" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I like the comment more where he moves the div IN the form. In your solution the div does absolutely nothing

Answer (score 0):

Your styling is one level higher in elements tree hierarchy and is not affecting `label`, `input` and `button` elements as their parent no longer contains required styles. So add styles to parent. Anyway you should add `form` tag at the top level of you form design

```
<form>
  <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row">
     <label id="email_label" for="email" style="padding-right:5px">Email:</label>
     <input id="email" type="email" name="email" style="flex:1" placeholder="enter email" />
     <button id="ack" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```